# Upload files and save in folder or save in database as binary

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if my question is basic or repeated question. I would like to know after uploading file (pdf,word,..) which condition is better
And when use each of these conditions

1- saving file in the folder and getting the file name for saving in the database

2- saving file in database as binary

Comment: It depends on how big the files are, how frequently you'll expect them to be accessed, security risks, etc.

Comment: Note that if you're using a service like Azure or AWS you should consider using Blob Storage - you can also use their Blob Storage services in general regardless of where your application resides provided it can communicate with the blob storage service.

Comment: Size of my files are different from 1 mb until 50 mb. Also count of files are around 100000 files and files related to different disciplines, i mean if i have to save in folders i have to make around 20 new folders , i am afraid about managing these folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If files are 'cold data' (not frequently used by system/users)  I will recommend saving them as binary zipped files in folder/blob/whatever-no-sql with name reference in relational database (if needed).

If files are 'hot data' (frequently used) - you can consider keeping some of them directly in relational database or any-fast-access-memory-solution with some automated process for coping old and not used documents to folder/blob

Comment: My files are hot and count of them is around 100000 and for each file usually i receive 5 different versions, usually we need last revision but sometimes we need also old versions.